# Content versions missing in copying content across CQ5 Environments

Tags: aem, crx

I have a question related with Adobe CQ5 content migration. We have two CQ5 environments.E1 and E2. We copied content of E1's author to E2's author instance. We did it by creating CRX content package. Our content copy went well but now we are realizing that we have missed our versions in pages. For example on E1 we hav a page example.html with three versions (1.0,1.2,1.3) but in E2 we are finding no version of example.html.

PS: We create versions manually by Author instance.

Answer (score 1):

The Package Manager only takes the latest version of a page and does not copy it's history. The only way to have the versions on both instances is using a cluster where the whole repository is synchronized.